# Android Studio device list stuck on loading

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[Picture of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r376E.jpg)

I'm trying to add my physical phone to the device list, however, the device list is stuck on loading.

I try to Kill adb process (on Task Manager on Windows) and Open Android Studio
And also I Try to reinstall Flutter and resetting the Flutter SDK, but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me this fixed the issue:

- First close the android studio and kill the all the related bg
  processes.
- Restart pc and check there are no bg processes running.
- Now connect your Android Device (make sure USB debug is enabled).
- Revoke the debug permissions and then allow debugging.
- Now on pc run `adb devices` command from terminal.
- If your device is displayed then proceed to open Android Studio and
  wait for some time.

Also make sure that there is only one version of adb is installed.